# Key error when pivoting a table even if the column exists

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that looks like this (this is just a small sample):

```
student     school      team       answers     question
a           scl         first      True        x
a           scl         first      False       y
a           scl         first      True        y
b           scl         first      False       x
c           scl         sec        False       y
c           scl         sec        True        z
d           scl         sec        True        x
d           scl         sec        True        z
e           scl         third      True        z
e           scl         third      False       z
```

I want to do a ranking that looks like this:

```
df_overall=
      question  first  sec  third
0            x    0.5  1.0    NaN
1            y    0.5  0.0    NaN
2            z    NaN  1.0    0.5
```

So I wrote:

```
df_overall = df.groupby(['team', 'question'])['answers'].apply(lambda x: x.sum()/len(x)).reset_index()
df_overall = df_overall.sort_values(by=['question']).rename(columns={'answers': 'TeamRanking'})
df_overall = df_overall.pivot_table(index='question', columns='team', values='TeamRanking').reset_index().rename_axis(None, axis=1)
```

But it gives me a `KeyError: 'team'` in the last line. If I run just the first two lines, it works. I tried putting `['team']` in brackets, and I checked the columns `print (df.columns.tolist())` and they are all there, no blank spaces, no weird writing. The `dtypes` are all objects except `answers` which is bool. I really don't understand why it's not finding it

Comment: FYI. Your code works well with your sample for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `pivot_table`:

```
>>> df.pivot_table(index='question', columns='team', values='answers')

team      first  sec  third
question                   
x           0.5  1.0    NaN
y           0.5  0.0    NaN
z           NaN  1.0    0.5
```

> I also considered the case where I only take the first answer of a student into consideration and I ignore the fact that they answered the same question several times

```
>>> df.drop_duplicates(['student', 'team', 'question']) \
      .pivot_table(index='question', columns='team', values='answers')

team      first  sec  third
question                   
x           0.5  1.0    NaN
y           0.0  0.0    NaN
z           NaN  1.0    1.0
```

Comment: Thank you your answer works! As for the bug, that might have been just a typo when I wrote the question, but in my own data it is `team` and it appears also in the least of columns as `team`, just like it appears in the KeyError.

Answer (score 0):

Pivot and drop multi-index column, code below

```
 newdf =pd.pivot_table(df,index='question', columns=['team'], aggfunc=np.mean).droplevel(0, axis=1).reset_index()

team question  first  sec  third
0           x    0.5  1.0    NaN
1           y    0.5  0.0    NaN
2           z    NaN  1.0    0.5
```

Comment: Thank you! I only have one question: can I still use my code? In my analysis, I also considered the case where I only take the first answer of a student into consideration and I ignore the fact that they answered the same question several times. I wrote: `df_first = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['student', 'team', 'question'], keep='first').groupby(['student', 'question'])['answer'].apply(lambda x: x.sum()/len(x)).reset_index()
df_first = df_first.sort_values(by=['question']).rename(columns={'answer: 'TeamRanking'})`, and the last line like above where I get the error.